# 'list' object is not callable, Python error

Tags: python, list, function, integer

I am trying to make a python function that receives two integers and returns a list of a descending order starting from the largest integer. (ex: f(2,5)=[5,4,3,2])

This is what I tried:

```
def f(n1: int, n2: int) -> List(int):
    if n1>n2:
        L=list(range(n2,n1+1))
        L.reverse()
    elif n1==n2:
        L=[n1]
    else:
        L=list(range(n1,n2+1))
        L.reverse()
    return L
```

the problem is I keep getting an error saying "'list' object is not callable" at List(int).
What is wrong with List(int), please?

Comment: You wanted `[]` not `()` - `List[int]`

Comment: How do you call the function? Could you provide executable code from scratch please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is syntax error in type annotation. For more info I recommend to read official docs about it https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html.
To solve it you need to change `List(int)` to `List[int]`. In python the `()` operator is so call `callable` operator and performs e.g function call like `f(1, 2)`

Comment: when I change it to List[int] I get "list indices must be integers or slices, not type" error..:(

Comment: I wanted to create a list containing one integer when n1=n2, for example f(1,1)=[1]

Comment: Do you have `from typing import List` statement on top of the file?

Comment: Oh, it worked after adding this statement. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

L is a object you have created.you should call the function f.

```
def f(n1: int, n2: int):
    if n1>n2:
        L=list(range(n2,n1+1))
        L.reverse()
    elif n1==n2:
        L=[n1]
    else:
        L=list(range(n1,n2+1))
        L.reverse()
    return L
f(2,5)
```

Comment: `L` has nothing to do with it, you could replace all but the first line of code in the op's post with `pass` and you'd still get the same error.

Comment: Got it..I thought jin is talking about calling L when saying List is not callable..Now understand first line  return annotation should be list[int] if annotation is needed..Thanks for the info